# C++ for loop is not interating correctly. It is stopping at first iteration

Tags: c++

I have a homework assignment. I have to create a function that takes the spaces out of string and output the result. For some reason,  my for loop is not interating and I am not sure why that is happening. here is my code:

```
int main() {

   string userInput;
   string result;
   string letter;


   cin >> userInput;

   result = "";

   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < userInput.size() - 1; ++i){
      letter = userInput.at(i);
      if(userInput.at(i) != ' '){
         result.append(letter);
      }
   }

   cout << result << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `; i < userInput.size() - 1;` should be `; i < userInput.size() ;`

Comment: First step of debugging your program is to check your inputs.  A simple `cout << userInput << endl` after the `cin` call would have made the problem obvious.

Comment: Side note:  If `userInput.size()` is ever 0, then you're going to have an underflow problem when you compute `userInput.size()-1`.  Assuming you really do want to ignore the last character in the string, you might therefore want to use with `(i+1) < userInput.size` instead.

Answer (score 5):

It probably appears to be stopping at the first letter because:

```
cin >> userInput;
```

will only read a string up to the first whitespace.

In other words, if you enter `hello there`, you'll only get `hello`.

You probably want to use `getline()` to ensure you get the entire line:

```
getline(cin, userInput).
```

You also want to change the continuation condition of your loop. Subtracting one from the string length will make you miss the last character. It should instead be:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < userInput.size(); ++i) {
```